# Measuring distance between two points using GeoTools java lib?

Tags: geotools

I am using [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/) to convert X and Y coordinates into points and get the distance between two points. I know that my coordinates are EPSG:32630 Name:WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N (https://epsg.io/32630). Then I created this small test to check the distance between two points. I am not sure if I am converting the X and Y coordinates correctly. And when I transform it to Points it throws an exception.

```
    Coordinate coordRad01 = new Coordinate(729664.353, 4373064.801);
    Coordinate coordRad02 = new Coordinate(730021.116, 4373070.406);
    Coordinate coordPoi01 = null;
    Coordinate coordPoi02 = null;
    MathTransform transformRadiusToPoint;
    try {
        CoordinateReferenceSystem radiusCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:32630", true);
        CoordinateReferenceSystem pointCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);

        DirectPosition dp01 = JTS.toDirectPosition(coordRad01, radiusCRS);
        DirectPosition dp02 = JTS.toDirectPosition(coordRad02, radiusCRS);
        System.out.println("DirectPosition dp01: " + dp01 + " dp02: " + dp02);

        Double distance = JTS.orthodromicDistance(coordRad01, coordRad02, radiusCRS);
        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance + " meters");

        transformRadiusToPoint = CRS.findMathTransform(pointCRS, radiusCRS);
        coordPoi01 = JTS.transform(coordRad01, coordPoi01, transformRadiusToPoint);
        coordPoi02 = JTS.transform(coordRad02, coordPoi02, transformRadiusToPoint);

        distance = JTS.orthodromicDistance(coordPoi01, coordPoi02, pointCRS);
        System.out.println("Distance: " + distance + " meters");
    } catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FactoryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

error:

```
DirectPosition dp01: JTS.[729664.353, 4373064.801] dp02: JTS.[730021.116, 4373070.406]
Distance: 356.7176800591084 meters
Jul 23, 2019 12:40:26 PM org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.TransverseMercator transform
WARNING: Possible use of "Transverse_Mercator" projection outside its valid area.
Longitude 729304°21.2'E is out of range (±180°).
Latitude 4372704°48.0'N is out of range (±90°).
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Longitude 5449761°17.2'E is out of range (±180°).
    at org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator.checkLongitude(GeodeticCalculator.java:406)
    at org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator.setStartingGeographicPoint(GeodeticCalculator.java:549)
    at org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator.setStartingPosition(GeodeticCalculator.java:591)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS.orthodromicDistance(JTS.java:635)
    at org.sense.flink.pojo.Point.main(Point.java:105)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** You have your transform backwards, you want to go from transverse mercator **to** WGS84 so it needs to be:

```
transformRadiusToPoint = CRS.findMathTransform(radiusCRS, pointCRS);
```

But you shouldn't need to convert to a geographic projection just to get the distance if your points are already in a planar/projected projection (CRS). I would simply use Pythagoras:

```
double d = Math.sqrt((coordRad01.x - coordRad02.x) * (coordRad01.x - coordRad02.x)
    + (coordRad01.y - coordRad02.y) * (coordRad01.y - coordRad02.y));
```

This then gives:

```
d=356.8070265480071
DirectPosition dp01: JTS.[729664.353, 4373064.801] dp02: JTS.[730021.116, 4373070.406]
Distance: 356.71768006444 meters
Distance: 356.71768006444 meters
```

Which all agree nicely.

Comment: thanks! this is even simpler